# Django TemplateView threw "didn't return an HttpResponse object" at dispatch

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

Given a homepage `TemplateView`, I want to redirect my user to a certain main dashboard page when he is logged in. I decided to do so via the `dispatch` method:

```
class HomeView(FormMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    error_message = ""

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
            return redirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            super(HomeView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The code is fine when the user is logged in. It does get redirected to the redirect view. However, when the user is not logged in, this view throws the following error:

```
ValueError: The view home_app.views.HomeView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Even after I override the `get` and `post` method, it still threw the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: You forgot the `return` before `super()`.

Comment: looks like an amateur error! thanks!

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not return after else that's why when you are authenticated it's return None